# fs.copyFileSync doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm using `Node.js` to copy a few files for one of my packages. My `OS` is `Windows 10 Pro`. When I run the `JS` file (tried in `cmd`, `powershell` and `cmd` with admin) absolutely nothing happens. No error, no copy. Here's the code:

```js
#! /usr/bin/env node
let fs = require("fs");
let path = require("path");

let rootPath = path.join(__dirname, "..");

let root = fs.readdirSync(rootPath);

let exclude = [
    ".git",
    ".gitignore",
    ".prettierrc",
    "bin",
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
];

root = root.filter((item) => exclude.indexOf(item) === -1);

let rootFiles = root.filter((item) =>
    fs.statSync(path.join(__dirname, "..", item)).isFile()
);

let rootFolders = root.filter((item) =>
    fs.statSync(path.join(__dirname, "..", item)).isDirectory()
);

for (let file of rootFiles) {
    let filePath = path.join(rootPath, file);
    let destinationPath = path.join(process.cwd(), file);

    if (!fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
        fs.copyFileSync(filePath, destinationPath);
    }
}

process.exit(0);
```

Comment: You call copyFileSync if file path doesn't exist, that's probably the problem